# Call a block on a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Instead of defining a scope in a class like this:

```
 scope :first_user, -> { first }
```

And calling it like this: `User.first_user`

I would like to define a block in another class, that can be called on the user class and works like a Scope:

This code is not working but it should signalize what behaviour I want to achieve:

```
class Manage

 def get_first_user
    User.&first_added
 end

 def first_added
   Proc.new { first }
 end
end
```

When I run this code:

```
a = Manage.new
a.get_first_user
```

it says me, `& undefined method for User`.  **How can I execute the Block defined in `first_added` on the User model?**

How can I in general call a block on a class?  Thanks

Comment: what does `User#first_added` look like?

Comment: From above code I can suggest you to rethink architecture of application. One way to execute block in the context of another class is to define method in that class that "executes" it.

Comment: Why not just call `User.first` in `get_first_user`? If this is like a Ruby experiment, keep at it. If you're trying to get work done, why bother? You can just call methods on the User class. 

If you really want to add dynamic methods to a Ruby object, check out `class_eval` and `instance_eval`. With those, you can concoct any logic you want on any class or object you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [`class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-class_eval):

```
>> foo = Proc.new { count }
=> #<Proc:0x007f1aa7cacfd8@(pry):30>
>> Buyer.class_eval(&foo)
(30.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "buyers"
=> 1234
```

Or with your example:

```
class Manage
  def get_first_user
    User.class_eval(&first_added)
  end

  def first_added
    Proc.new { first }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not what you want but maybe this will be helpful.
I am not sure if one can call proc **on** something. I think one can only call proc **with** something, i.t. in your case passing `User` as parameter.

```
def get_first_user
  wrap User, &first_added
end

def first_added
  Proc.new { |model| model.where(...) }
end

private

def wrap(model, &block)
  yield model
end
```

Comment: But in the block I only want `where(..)` and this block should then somehwere else be called on User.Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes, I just think of it now! I try to update answer soon. Wait a minute)

Comment: Seems like you cannot call block on `User` model. You can only pass `User` model as parameter as I do in code above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's three ways to call `first` on `User` from `Manager` using:

- `Object#send`:
  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send
- `Module#class_eval`:
  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-class_eval

File `manage.rb`:

```
class User
  def self.first
    puts 'record would probably go here'
  end

  def self.yielder
    print "via yielder => "
    self.send(yield) if block_given?
  end

  def self.blocker(&block)
    print "via blocker => "
    self.send(block.call) if block_given?
  end

  def self.evaller(&block)
    print "via evaller => "
    self.class_eval(block.call) if block_given?
  end
end

class Manage
  def get_first_user
    User.yielder(&first_added)
    User.blocker(&first_added)
    User.evaller(&first_added)
  end

  def first_added
    Proc.new {"first"} 
  end 
end

a = Manage.new
a.get_first_user
```

Output:

```
$ ruby manage.rb 
via yielder => record would probably go here
via blocker => record would probably go here
via evaller => record would probably go here
```